# How to have two Request types of DELETE with the same signature in WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can I have two DELETE signatures in one WebApi like the code below?

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        if (id < 1) { return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { msg = "ID cannot be null" }); };
        try
        {
            GenericCatalogManagerBL.DeletePart(_genericCNN, id);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new { msg = "Part removed" });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { msg = "Part not removed" });
        }
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int genericCatalogID)
    {
        if (genericCatalogID < 1) { return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { msg = "GenericCatalogID cannot be null" }); };
        try
        {
            GenericCatalogManagerBL.DeletePartsAll(_genericCNN, genericCatalogID);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new { msg = "Parts removed" });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { msg = "Parts not removed" });
            }
```

}

Comment: Why do you need two same methods?

Comment: You can't.  How would you expect compiler to resolve `Delete(5)` call?  Method signature has to be unique!  Just rename your method - see answer below in a sec...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
{
    if (id < 1) { return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { msg = "ID cannot be null" }); };
    try
    {
        GenericCatalogManagerBL.DeletePart(_genericCNN, id);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new { msg = "Part removed" });
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { msg = "Part not removed" });
    }
}

public HttpResponseMessage DeleteByCatalogID(int genericCatalogID)
{
    if (genericCatalogID < 1) { return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { msg = "GenericCatalogID cannot be null" }); };
    try
    {
        GenericCatalogManagerBL.DeletePartsAll(_genericCNN, genericCatalogID);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted, new { msg = "Parts removed" });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, new { msg = "Parts not removed" });
        }
```

and map routes accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

Your example violates overloading rules, there has to be some distinguishing signature.  Other than adding another argument the only solution is to rename one of your methods.

Answer (score 0):

At the level you're discussing it here, your problem is you can't distinguish between the two at all.

At the level of the actual HTTP request, you'd have the same problem; a `DELETE` to a URI means delete the resource represented by that URI; there's no "different types of deletion", it's deleted.

However, there's no reason why one resource can't represent some or all features of another resource or set of resources. Define resources with separate URIs to represent that (and hence, classes an the C# level), and differentiate between deletions by which type of object you try to delete. Alternatively, map `DELETE`s to a particular URI pattern to a different method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two actions with identical signatures. You can however use the following:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int? id, int? genericCatalogID)
{
    // Your logic here
}
```

You will just have to take into account what happens if both parameters have a value.